# Cómo renderizo la data consumida de una API con next app router

Tags: api, wordpress, app, routes, nextjs13

siguiendo la documentación de next cree un archivo api\posts\route.js con:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(process.env.WP_API_URL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Contendt-type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    const posts = await result.json()
    return NextResponse.json({data: posts})
};
```

Funciona, ahora lo que no logro hacer es renderizarlo. Soy nuevo con Next y esto me tiene trabado. Mi país no tiene acceso a chatGPT, así que no me puedo ayudar con eso por si alguien lo piensa comentar.